# CF template to create sparkUI history server is failing

Tags: amazon-web-services, pyspark, yaml, aws-cloudformation, spark-ui

Default CF Template to create a history server includes creation of security group and IAM role.
I removed both and added to select the existing security group.
Now when I am running my CF template it is successfully creating the HistoryServerInstance but it is failing in wait condition.
can you you guys help where i am going wrong.
Error screenshot and script attached.

thanks.

[image: Error Scrrenshot]

My CF template in yaml:

```
Parameters:
  InstanceType:
    Type: String
    Default: t3.medium
    AllowedValues:
      - t3.micro
      - t3.small
      - t3.medium
    Description: Instance Type for EC2 instance which hosts Spark history server.
  LatestAmiId:
    Type: AWS::SSM::Parameter::Value<AWS::EC2::Image::Id>
    Description: Latest AMI ID of Amazon Linux 2 for Spark history server instance. You can use the default value.
    Default: /aws/service/ami-amazon-linux-latest/amzn2-ami-hvm-x86_64-gp2
  InstanceSecurityGroup:
    Description: "Select Security Group"
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup::Id
  VpcId:
    Type: AWS::EC2::VPC::Id
    Description: "VPC ID for Spark history server instance."
    Default: '' 
  SubnetId:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet::Id
    Description: Subnet ID for Spark history server instance.
    Default: ''
  IpAddressRange:
    Type: String
    Description: "IP address range that can be used to view the Spark UI."
    MinLength: 9
    MaxLength: 18
  HistoryServerPort:
    Type: Number
    Description: History Server Port for the Spark UI.
    Default: 18080
    MinValue: 1150
    MaxValue: 65535
  EventLogDir:
    Type: String
    Description: "*Event Log Directory* where Spark event logs are stored from the Glue job or dev endpoints. You must use s3a:// for the event logs path scheme"
    Default: s3a://hcg-stagingaas6377-sandbox/logs/
  SparkPackageLocation:
    Type: String
    Description: You can use the default value.
    Default: 'https://archive.apache.org/dist/spark/spark-2.4.3/spark-2.4.3-bin-without-hadoop.tgz'
  KeystorePath:
    Type: String
    Description: SSL/TLS keystore path for HTTPS. If you want to use custom keystore file, you can specify the S3 path s3://path_to_your_keystore_file here. If you leave this parameter empty, self-signed certificate based keystore is used.
  KeystorePassword:
    Type: String
    NoEcho: true
    Description: SSL/TLS keystore password for HTTPS. A valid password can contain 6 to 30 characters.
    MinLength: 6
    MaxLength: 30

Metadata:
  AWS::CloudFormation::Interface:
    ParameterGroups:
      -
        Label:
          default: Spark UI Configuration
        Parameters:
          - IpAddressRange
          - HistoryServerPort
          - EventLogDir
          - SparkPackageLocation
          - KeystorePath
          - KeystorePassword
      -
        Label:
          default: EC2 Instance Configuration
        Parameters:
          - InstanceType
          - LatestAmiId
          - VpcId
          - SubnetId

Mappings:
  MemoryBasedOnInstanceType:
    t3.micro:
      SparkDaemonMemory: '512m'
    t3.small:
      SparkDaemonMemory: '1g'
    t3.medium:
      SparkDaemonMemory: '3g'

Resources:
  HistoryServerInstance:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
    Properties:
      ImageId: !Ref LatestAmiId
      InstanceType: !Ref InstanceType
      SubnetId: !Ref SubnetId
      SecurityGroupIds: 
      - !Ref InstanceSecurityGroup
      UserData:
        'Fn::Base64': !Sub |
          #!/bin/bash -xe
          yum update -y aws-cfn-bootstrap
          echo "CA_OVERRIDE=/etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt" >> /etc/environment
          export CA_OVERRIDE=/etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
          rpm -Uvh https://s3.amazonaws.com/amazoncloudwatch-agent/amazon_linux/amd64/latest/amazon-cloudwatch-agent.rpm
          /opt/aws/bin/cfn-init -v -s ${AWS::StackName} -r HistoryServerInstance --region ${AWS::Region}
          /opt/aws/bin/cfn-signal -e -s ${AWS::StackName} -r HistoryServerInstance --region ${AWS::Region}
    Metadata:
      AWS::CloudFormation::Init:
        configSets:
          default:
            - cloudwatch_agent_configure
            - cloudwatch_agent_restart
            - spark_download
            - spark_init
            - spark_configure
            - spark_hs_start
            - spark_hs_test
        cloudwatch_agent_configure:
          files:
            /opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/etc/amazon-cloudwatch-agent.json:
              content: !Sub |
                  {
                    "logs": {
                      "logs_collected": {
                        "files": {
                          "collect_list": [
                            {
                              "file_path": "/var/log/cfn-init.log",
                              "log_group_name": "/aws-glue/sparkui_cfn/cfn-init.log"
                            },
                            {
                              "file_path": "/opt/spark/logs/spark-*",
                              "log_group_name": "/aws-glue/sparkui_cfn/spark_history_server.log"
                            }
                          ]
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
        cloudwatch_agent_restart:
          commands:
            01_stop_service:
              command: /opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/bin/amazon-cloudwatch-agent-ctl -a stop
            02_start_service:
              command: /opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/bin/amazon-cloudwatch-agent-ctl -a fetch-config -m ec2 -c file:/opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/etc/amazon-cloudwatch-agent.json -s
        spark_download:
          packages:
            yum:
              java-1.8.0-openjdk: []
              maven: []
              python3: []
              python3-pip: []
          sources:
            /opt: !Ref SparkPackageLocation
          commands:
            create-symlink:
              command: ln -s /opt/spark-* /opt/spark
            export:
              command: !Sub |
                echo "export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jre" | sudo tee -a /etc/profile.d/jdk.sh
                echo "export SPARK_HOME=/opt/spark" | sudo tee -a /etc/profile.d/spark.sh
                export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jre
                export SPARK_HOME=/opt/spark
            download-pom-xml:
              command: curl -o /tmp/pom.xml https://aws-glue-sparkui-prod-us-east-1.s3.amazonaws.com/public/mvn/pom.xml
            download-setup-py:
              command: curl -o /tmp/setup.py https://aws-glue-sparkui-prod-us-east-1.s3.amazonaws.com/public/misc/setup.py
            download-systemd-file:
              command: curl -o /usr/lib/systemd/system/spark-history-server.service https://aws-glue-sparkui-prod-us-east-1.s3.amazonaws.com/public/misc/spark-history-server.service
        spark_init:
          commands:
            download-mvn-dependencies:
              command: cd /tmp; mvn dependency:copy-dependencies -DoutputDirectory=/opt/spark/jars/
            install-boto:
              command: pip3 install boto --user; pip3 install boto3 --user
          files:
            /opt/spark/conf/spark-defaults.conf:
              content: !Sub |
                spark.eventLog.enabled                      true
                spark.history.fs.logDirectory               ${EventLogDir}
                spark.history.ui.port                       0
                spark.ssl.historyServer.enabled             true
                spark.ssl.historyServer.port                ${HistoryServerPort}
                spark.ssl.historyServer.keyStorePassword    ${KeystorePassword}
              group: ec2-user
              mode: '000644'
              owner: ec2-user
            /opt/spark/conf/spark-env.sh:
              content: !Sub
                - |
                  export SPARK_DAEMON_MEMORY=${SparkDaemonMemoryConfig}
                  export SPARK_HISTORY_OPTS="$SPARK_HISTORY_OPTS -Dspark.hadoop.fs.s3.impl=org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem"
                - SparkDaemonMemoryConfig: !FindInMap [ MemoryBasedOnInstanceType, !Ref InstanceType, SparkDaemonMemory ]
              group: ec2-user
              mode: '000644'
              owner: ec2-user
        spark_configure:
          commands:
            create-symlink:
              command: ln -s /usr/lib/systemd/system/spark-history-server.service /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/
            enable-spark-hs:
              command: systemctl enable spark-history-server
            configure-keystore:
              command: !Sub |
                python3 /tmp/setup.py --keystore "${KeystorePath}" --keystorepw "${KeystorePassword}" > /tmp/setup_py.log 2>&1
        spark_hs_start:
          commands:
            start_spark_hs_server:
              command: systemctl start spark-history-server
        spark_hs_test:
          commands:
            check-spark-hs-server:
              command: !Sub |
                curl --retry 60 --retry-delay 10 --retry-max-time 600 --retry-connrefused https://localhost:${HistoryServerPort} --insecure;
                /opt/aws/bin/cfn-signal -e $? "${WaitHandle}"
  WaitHandle:
    Type: AWS::CloudFormation::WaitConditionHandle
  WaitCondition:
    Type: AWS::CloudFormation::WaitCondition
    DependsOn: HistoryServerInstance
    Properties:
      Handle: !Ref WaitHandle
      Timeout: 1200

Outputs:
  SparkUiPublicUrl:
    Description: The Public URL of Spark UI
    Value: !Join
      - ''
      - - 'https://'
        - !GetAtt 'HistoryServerInstance.PublicDnsName'
        - ':'
        - !Ref HistoryServerPort
  SparkUiPrivateUrl:
    Description: The Private URL of Spark UI
    Value: !Join
      - ''
      - - 'https://'
        - !GetAtt 'HistoryServerInstance.PrivateDnsName'
        - ':'
        - !Ref HistoryServerPort
  CloudWatchLogsCfnInit:
    Description: CloudWatch Logs Console URL for cfn-init.log in History Server Instance
    Value: !Join
      - ''
      - - 'https://console.aws.amazon.com/cloudwatch/home?region='
        - !Ref AWS::Region
        - '#logEventViewer:group=/aws-glue/sparkui_cfn/cfn-init.log;stream='
        - !Ref HistoryServerInstance
  CloudWatchLogsSparkHistoryServer:
    Description: CloudWatch Logs Console URL for spark history server logs in History Server Instance
    Value: !Join
      - ''
      - - 'https://console.aws.amazon.com/cloudwatch/home?region='
        - !Ref AWS::Region
        - '#logEventViewer:group=/aws-glue/sparkui_cfn/spark_history_server.log;stream='
        - !Ref HistoryServerInstance
```

Comment: You have to login to the instance after it boots and fails and inspect log files in `/var/log/` to see why your UserData and Metadata are failing.

Comment: The instance which is created doesn't have a key pair...so I can't connect to the machine.

Comment: You can setup SSM Session manager if you want. Either way, primary way if troubleshooting such cases is by examination of logs.

Comment: Thanks Marcin...l'll try to examine logs.

Comment: Hi @Marcin I checked the logs...every statement is getting executed but at the end my connection is getting refused.

this is what i am getting:

'
Command check-spark-hs-server output:   % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
^M  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0Warning: Transient problem: connection refused Will retry in 10 seconds. 60
Warning: retries left.
'

Comment: So `curl --retry 60 --retry-delay 10 --retry-max-time 600 --retry-connrefused https://localhost:${HistoryServerPort} --insecure` fails. So you have to investigate why? For example, are you sure that port is ok? Are you sure it should be https, not http? And so on. Best to login into the instance and run the command from there.

Answer (score 0):

I had a more detailed look at your case. The template you are trying to deploy is **missing IAM role** for the instance; subsequently, `spark-history-server` fails to start.

I would suggest using the **original template provided by AWS**:

- [Launching the Spark History Server and Viewing the Spark UI Using AWS CloudFormation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/monitor-spark-ui-history.html#monitor-spark-ui-history-cfn)

which has the missing IAM role. I **verified** that it works, as I deployed it in my sandbox account in `us-east-1` region.